# Raspberry PI Button Push Listener

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

Is it possible to have  button push listener in Python for the Raspberry Pi.  I have a non-latching button going to a GPIO.  I want to run some python code the first time the button is pushed.  Then I want the code to stop on the second button push no matter where it is in the first line of code.

I've used a toggle bit variable called "flag" to register button pushes but obviously there is no listener to determine when the second push is made.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

Button = 16    # pin16

def setup():

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)          # Numbers GPIOs by physical location
    GPIO.setup(Button, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)   # Button Input

def motorcontrol():
    flag=0
    while True:
        j=GPIO.input(16)
        if j==1: #Robot is activated when button is pressed
            flag=1
            print "Robot Activated",j
        while flag==1:    
            time.sleep(5)
            print "Robot Activated for 5 seconds"
            time.sleep(5)
            print "Robot Activated for 10 seconds"
            time.sleep(5)
            print "Robot Activated for 15 seconds"

            j=GPIO.input(16)
            if j==1: #De activate robot on pushing the button
                flag=0
                print "Robot DeActivated",j
                destroy()

def destroy():
    GPIO.cleanup()                     # Release resource               

if __name__ == '__main__':     # Program start from here
    setup()
    try:
        motorcontrol()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  # When 'Ctrl+C' is pressed, the child program destroy() will be  executed.
        destroy()
```

Comment: http://razzpisampler.oreilly.com/ch07.html

Comment: you can't use `sleep()` because it blocks your code. You shoulf  do somethink like: at start set `first_text = current_time + 5 seconds` and later in loop check `if current_time >= first_text: print "Robot Activated for 5 seconds"`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `sleep()` this way because your `while` loop can't check your botton. You have to loop all time and check if it is time to display text.

You can use small `sleep()` to use lees CPU.

```
import time

current_time = time.time()

text_1 = current_time + 5
text_2 = current_time + 10
text_3 = current_time + 15

flag = True

while flag:

    # TODO: check your button and change `flag`

    current_time = time.time()

    if text_1 and current_time >= text_1:
        print("5 seconds")
        text_1 = None #  to stop displaying
        # or show again after 5 seconds
        #text_1 = current_time + 5

    if text_2 and current_time >= text_2:
        print("10 seconds")
        text_2 = None #  to stop displaying

    if text_3 and current_time >= text_3:
        print("15 seconds")
        text_3 = None #  to stop displaying
        flag = False

    #time.sleep(0.1)
```

Or more like in most GUI

```
import time

# --- functions ---

def callback_1():
    print("5 seconds")

    # add new task to list
    tasks.append( (current_time + 5, callback_1) )

def callback_2():
    print("10 seconds")

def callback_3():
    print("15 seconds")

def callback_4():
    global flag
    flag = False

# --- main ---

current_time = time.time()

tasks = []

tasks.append( (current_time + 5, callback_1) )
tasks.append( (current_time + 10, callback_2) )
tasks.append( (current_time + 15, callback_3) )
tasks.append( (current_time + 17, callback_4) )

flag = True

while flag:

    # TODO: check your button

    current_time = time.time()

    # this way I execute task and remove from list
    new_tasks = []

    for t, c in tasks:
        if current_time >= t:
            c()
        else:
            new_tasks.append( (t,c) )

    tasks = new_tasks

    #time.sleep(0.1)
```

---

**EDIT:** I don't have RPi so I try to simulate it using own class `GPIO` - but maybe it will work on your computer. It shows where you should put code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

'''
#
# for test only - instead of `import RPi.GPIO as GPIO`
#

# simulate button press
current_time = time.time()
button_1 = current_time + 2
button_2 = current_time + 10

class GPIO:
    BOARD = None
    IN = None
    PUD_DOWN = None

    @staticmethod
    def setmode(a):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def setup(a, b, pull_up_down=None):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def input(a):
        global button_1, button_2

        current_time = time.time()

        if button_1 and current_time >= button_1:
            button_1 = None
            return 1

        if button_2 and current_time >= button_2:
            button_2 = None
            return 1

        return 0

    @staticmethod
    def cleanup():
        pass
'''

Button = 16    # pin16

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)          # Numbers GPIOs by physical location
    GPIO.setup(Button, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)   # Button Input

def motorcontrol():
    flag = False

    while True:
        j = GPIO.input(16)
        if j == 1:
            flag = True

            print "Robot Activated", j
            current_time = time.time()

            text_1 = current_time + 5
            text_2 = current_time + 10
            text_3 = current_time + 15

        while flag:    
            j = GPIO.input(16)
            if j == 1:
                flag = False
                print "Robot DeActivated", j
                destroy()

            current_time = time.time()

            if text_1 and current_time >= text_1:
                print "5 seconds"
                text_1 = None #  to stop displaying
                # or show again after 5 seconds
                #text_1 = current_time + 5

            if text_2 and current_time >= text_2:
                print "10 seconds"
                text_2 = None #  to stop displaying

            if text_3 and current_time >= text_3:
                print "15 seconds"
                text_3 = None #  to stop displaying
                flag = False

            time.sleep(0.1)

def destroy():
    GPIO.cleanup()      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    try:
        motorcontrol()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  
        destroy()
```

Comment: That's good stuff.  Thanks. However the first code when run produces all lines of text at the same time without waiting for the 5 seconds because the while loop doesn't start until I click the button for the first time (initiating the code) so current_time is always greater than text_3.  When I try to update the current time and the text_1 after first button press I get the following error 'text_1 = current_time + 5 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: builtin_function_or_method and int'

Comment: My plan was to start the program with the button and have my robot travel a square path repeatedly until I press the button a second time to end the program.  I was planning to use time.sleep to control how long each motor was on for hence the above test code piece.